# Simple import problem

Tags: java, syntax, package

I'm trying to learn java and seem to be missing something obvious.

In subdirectory lab I have the file Play.java

```
package lab;
import java.io.*;

public class Play {
    public static void playprint(Object obj) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

My CLASSPATH starts with '.'

In the parent directory I have a program

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
       lab.Play.playprint("hello world");
   }
}
```

This runs fine. If I change the program to

```
import lab.Play.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        playprint("hello world");
    }
}
```

It fails with an error that it can't find symbol method playprint

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To import a method you have to use *import static*. Without you are trying to import all classes (and interfaces) within your class "Play" only.

```
import static lab.Play.*;
```

See [the documentation on static imports](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip using static methods, you can create an *object of `Play` class* inside the class test and then call playprint.